# How do I echo just 1 column of output from ls command?

Tags: bash, ls, parameter, arguments

Lets say when I do ls command the output is:

```
file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Is it possible to display only a certain column of output, in this case file2? I have tried the following with no success:

```
echo ls | $2
```

Basically all I want to do is echo only the second column, in this case, I want to echo:

```
file2
```

Comment: What is a situation in which you really want a *column* of `ls` output?

Comment: As a general rule, you should [never parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). There are almost _always_ better ways of getting the info you need.

Comment: I wouldn't do that stranger :P (sorry I allways liked that phrase) the number of columns depend on the names files and folders have, so 2nd column may be the one you want, or may not, or may be in one `ls` and after creating some files/folders it may no longer be what you want. As terdon pointed out there sure are better ways to get what you want

Comment: grep -l "" *    (small hack)

Answer (score 143):

The following command will format the `ls` output into one column:

```
ls -1 /directory
```

Comment: But it doesn't give you just the one column the OP is interested in.

Comment: To make it correct : `ls -1 /directory | head -2 | tail -1` or `ls -1 /directory | perl -ne 'print if $. == 2'`

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz `ls | sed -n '1p;q'` seems simpler

Comment: The answer I was looking for, but not for the question of OP.

Comment: It's the answer to what you would assume the overview question in the title means, and it has lots of votes and good answers, therefore is the top google hit, which keeps reinforcing that feedback loop.

Comment: worth pointing out that `-1` is `minus digit-one` not `minus lower-case-L`, as it can be a bit difficult to tell the difference when viewing it

Answer (score 46):

The most reliable way to do this is to put the files into an array, and get the second one, which avoids having to do any parsing at all:

```
files=(*)
printf '%s\n' "${files[1]}"
```

The order in which you get back the files depends on the value of `LC_COLLATE`. As such, you might want to set `LC_COLLATE=C` first, if you want a "standard" sorting in all corner cases.

Comment: Note that array indices start at `1` in sensible shells (zsh, yash, fish, csh, tcsh, rc, es...) and at `0` in ksh and bash. For a solution portable to all Bourne-like shells, you could use: `set -- *; printf '%s\n' "$2"` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas At least for this question, the tags include "bash", so this answer is specific to that shell.

Comment: ls -C | awk '{ print $1 } looks give same output ... why $2 ?

Answer (score 19):

You would need to add `-C` as `ls` uses single-column mode when the output is not a terminal.  `awk` then prints the second column:

```
ls -C | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: This may not do what you want it to if your filenames contain spaces or other whitespace characters.

Comment: Parsing `ls` is anyway not they way to go to fetch a filename for exactly this reason, but the question was about the 2nd column of that output. In general, `find` to the rescue!

Answer (score 12):

I think you are looking for

```
ls -1
```

It won't show permission, owner, group, date, size... but simple file name in single column.

Comment: Not only is this answer wrong, but *it's been given before.*

Comment: Although I realize this is wrong for the original question, it is what I was looking for. So, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As already has been mentioned - using columns for parsing `ls` output is not very robust because `ls` breaks the lines according to your file name lengths and terminal width. 
It often is interesting though to display a single column of a list of elements.
You can do this using the cut command:

```
echo file1 file2 file3 file4 | cut -d" "  -f2
```

will display

```
file2
```

Note that `-d` allows you to select the column delimiter, 
so for example with

```
cut -d, -f2
```

you can display the second column of a comma separated list.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled on this that seems to work:

```
(base) balter@winmac:~/winhome/gdsc_bq_etl/large_files/harmonized$ ls | cat
cell_lines_metadata.tsv
drug_metadata.tsv
gdsc1_anova_all_tcga_results.tsv
gdsc1_anova_pancancer_results.tsv
gdsc1_drug_ic50_resuults.tsv
gdsc2_anova_all_tcga_results.tsv
gdsc2_anova_pancancer_results.tsv
gdsc2_drug_ic50_results.tsv
genetic_features_all_tcga_metadata.tsv
genetic_features_all_tcga_results.tsv
genetic_features_pancancer_metadata.tsv
genetic_features_pancancer_results.tsv
```

Comment: This works perfectly regardless of terminal width and filename/foldername length. If you want only directories, use `ls -d */ | cat`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way works for me is adding "-al". That is:

```
ls -C -al | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Because `-al` add more columns like user, permissions, etc.

Comment: I don't think there's an `-all` flag. I think that should just be `-al` which is combining `-a` for including files and folders that start with `.` (normally hidden) and `-l` which is "Long Format" and puts one entry per line, including file size and permissions.

Comment: ammended. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the `-l` option override `-C`? Then what is the question you're answering? The question here is how to get the second filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_chars=54 # offset
ls -ltr | cut -c$num_chars-
```

change the number of characters (54) as necessary so you only get the data you want.

Comment: to clarify, using `54-` tells cut to every character starting at position 54; it doesn't stop at "human-recognized" column

Comment: It's not a bad idea..just needs to be refined.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to display only the particular filename under current path use below command

command:

```
find path -maxdepth 1 -iname "filename"|sed "s/\.\///g"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, because parsing `ls -C` depends on:

1. filename length, (which itself depends on the specified file list passed to `ls -C`)
2. terminal width.
3. the fact that `ls -C` output is columnar, but might be configured to varying numbers of spaces as field separators.
4. the possibility of whitespace in filenames, (the display of which depends upon the particular `ls` display options chosen).

For now, let's start with the easier problem, (*i.e.* not #4 above), **supposing** that there's **no whitespace in the filenames**.  To print column #2, this works:

```
COLUMNS=$COLUMNS ls -C | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f2
```

Unrolling that:

- `COLUMNS=$COLUMNS` guarantees that the column length fed to `|`
  remains consistent with the current terminal display.  Changing this
  to an arbitrary value works too, so `COLUMNS=50` or `COLUMNS=70`
  would cause `ls -C` to rearrange things according to those widths.

  Another method would be to use the `-w` switch, *e.g.*:

  ```
  ls -w${COLUMNS} -C | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f2
  ```
- `tr` makes the field separators consistent: a single *tab* between each column.
- `cut` outputs the desired column.

Comment: Whitespace method pending...

Answer (score 0):

To me the best answer is

```
$ ls -1 ../* | tr -s '\n' '\n'
../main.go
../main_test.go
../abort:
main.go
../beego:
beego
conf
controllers
go.mod
go.sum
lastupdate.tmp
main.go
routers
views
../bucket:
main.go
main_test.go
../c:
../cc:
main.go
main_test.go
```

It is the only command I found that supports multi directory traversing without blank lines and that outputs exactly 1 column like OP asked, and i needed to count them using `wc`!